Logging each item from ClassData and InlineData in xUnit
I want to log parameters' values in unit test methods that are provided by InlineData, ClassData or MemberData.
In some cases there are many item sets to pass to the unit test method, I want to know exactly which item set failed the test.
Is there any solution like global error handling in asp.net MVC or middleware in .net?
To centralize logging messages (in Visual Studio test output window and also in the console) and catching values passes to the unit test method.
I've found this article, but it just works for cases with InlineData. If there is ClassData attribute  on the test, it's not possible to catch the item sets each one.
https://andrewlock.net/tracking-down-a-hanging-xunit-test-in-ci-building-a-custom-test-framework/
I've tried the solution in this article:
https://andrewlock.net/tracking-down-a-hanging-xunit-test-in-ci-building-a-custom-test-framework/
But it does not work for case with CalssData or MemberData.
Also, it does not log messages to the VS test output windows, just logs messages into the console.
